# How do I rename A drive name, not the name of the mountpoint, in Windows 10?

Tags: windows

I have two Blu-ray drives installed and mounted like in the image:

[The Win explorer names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mfR88.png)

Now, when I view them in Device manager, they have these names:

[Device manager names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzdmB.png)

Now how can I rename these two, the literal drive names? I found no solutions online.

Comment: I'm not sure which of the names you're trying to change. Drive letter (`G:`), the helpful description (BD-ROM drive) which could change if there's a physical disk inserted, or the hardware name of the drive? Also, are you looking to write a program for this? Because otherwise you're on the wrong StackExchange site.

Comment: The drive-type names in the Windows shell are localized in shell32.dll.mui. For example, from "en-us\shell32.dll.mui": Audio CD, CD Drive, DVD Drive,  BD-ROM Drive, BD-RE Drive.

Comment: The drive names "G:" and "H:" are DOS device names, implemented as object symlinks to the corresponding NT volume device names in the "\Device" object directory. They are not mountpoints. When a volume device is mounted by a filesystem, the automatic mountpoint in Windows is the root path on the volume device, e.g. "G:\" and "H:\". Bind mountpoints (i.e. `IO_REPARSE_TAG_MOUNT_POINT`) can also be set on directories, e.g. something like "C:\Mount\bdrom0".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to change the drive names in device manager, it is [here](https://www.avoiderrors.com/rename-devices-device-manager/).